# An indefinite integral question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm learning indefinite integral and I got a question that says

When the given f function
$f(1+2x) + f(1-2x) = x^{2016}$
is a real number,

Solve
$\int_{-1}^3 f(x) \ dx$

The answer is supposed to be $2/2017$ but I don't understand why

Can anyone explain why it becomes like this please?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{-1}^3f(x)dx$?

Comment: Please use mathjax

Comment: @kingW3 yes it is

Comment: @Christopher Halverson Sorry I edited

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Put $x=1+2u$.

$$\int_{-1}^3f(x)dx=2\int_{-1}^1f(1+2u)du$$

Put $x=1-2v$.

$$\int_{-1}^3f(x)dx=-2\int_1^{-1}f(1-2v)dv=2\int_{-1}^1f(1-2v)dv$$

Therefore,

$$2\int_{-1}^3f(x)dx=2\int_{-1}^1f(1+2x)dx+2\int_{-1}^1f(1-2x)dx$$

We are now ready to use the given property of $f$.

Comment: Omg thank you so much. It makes far more sense now! Bless you!